# update function not working properly in c# not able to update to sql server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssms

hi i am Writing code to update the database but i am facing some problems hope you can guide me

So i want to update data on my my database through my mvc application

the following controller code works properly:-

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult  Edit_Get(int id)
{
    DealMasterBLL dealMasterBLL = new DealMasterBLL();
    DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo = dealMasterBLL.DealMasterInfo.Single(did => did.DealAutoID == Convert.ToString(id));
    return View(dealMasterInfo);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit_Post(DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        DealMasterBLL dealMasterBLL = new DealMasterBLL();
       // dealMasterInfo = dealMasterBLL.DealMasterInfo.Single(did => did.DealAutoID ==id);
       // UpdateModel(dealMasterInfo);
        dealMasterBLL.EditDealMaster(dealMasterInfo);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

but when i make changes in post method

Following Changes:-

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult  Edit_Get(int id)
{
    DealMasterBLL dealMasterBLL = new DealMasterBLL();
    DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo = dealMasterBLL.DealMasterInfo.Single(did => did.DealAutoID == Convert.ToString(id));
    return View(dealMasterInfo);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit_Post(int id)
{
    DealMasterBLL dealMasterBLL = new DealMasterBLL();
    DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo = dealMasterBLL.DealMasterInfo.Single(did => did.DealAutoID ==Convert.ToString(id));
    UpdateModel(dealMasterInfo);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        dealMasterBLL.EditDealMaster(dealMasterInfo);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

the code doesn't work
 i tried debugging but it goes through all the paths properly without any mistakes

i am adding all other required codes below please reply

business Layer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using SnackoEntities;

namespace BusinesssLayer
{
   public class DealMasterBLL
    {
        public IEnumerable<DealMasterInfo> DealMasterInfo
        {
            get
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DealMaster"].ConnectionString;

                List<DealMasterInfo> dealMasterInfos = new List<DealMasterInfo>();

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetDealMasterInfo", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo = new DealMasterInfo();
                        dealMasterInfo.DealAutoID = rdr["DealAutoID"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.FK_RestoID = rdr["FK_RestoID"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.FK_SnFoodID = rdr["FK_SnFoodID"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.DealDisPerc = rdr["DealDisPerc"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.FK_RewaID = rdr["FK_RewaID"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["startDate"]);
                        dealMasterInfo.endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["endDate"]);
                        dealMasterInfo.ValidOn = rdr["ValidOn"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.UserTypes = rdr["UserTypes"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.DealCode = rdr["DealCode"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.DealPic = rdr["DealPic"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.DealStatus = rdr["DealStatus"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.CreatedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["CreatedOn"]);
                        dealMasterInfo.ModifiedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["ModifiedOn"]);
                        dealMasterInfo.CreatedBy = rdr["CreatedBy"].ToString();

                        dealMasterInfos.Add(dealMasterInfo);
                    }
                }

                return dealMasterInfos;
            }
        }

        public void AddDealMaster(DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DealMaster"].ConnectionString;

            try
            {
                using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddDealMaster", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter paramDealAutoID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealAutoID.ParameterName = "@DealAutoID";
                    paramDealAutoID.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealAutoID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealAutoID);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_RestoID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_RestoID.ParameterName = "@FK_RestoID";
                    paramFK_RestoID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_RestoID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_RestoID);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_SnFoodID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_SnFoodID.ParameterName = "@FK_SnFoodID";
                    paramFK_SnFoodID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_SnFoodID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_SnFoodID);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_RoFoodID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_RoFoodID.ParameterName = "@FK_RoFoodID";
                    paramFK_RoFoodID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_RoFoodID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_RoFoodID);

                    SqlParameter paramDealDisPerc = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealDisPerc.ParameterName = "@DealDiscPerc";
                    paramDealDisPerc.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealDisPerc;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealDisPerc);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_RewaID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_RewaID.ParameterName = "@FK_RewaID";
                    paramFK_RewaID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_RewaID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_RewaID);

                    SqlParameter paramstartDate = new SqlParameter();
                    paramstartDate.ParameterName = "@startDate";
                    paramstartDate.Value = dealMasterInfo.startDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramstartDate);

                    SqlParameter paramendDate = new SqlParameter();
                    paramendDate.ParameterName = "@endDate";
                    paramendDate.Value = dealMasterInfo.endDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramendDate);

                    SqlParameter paramValidOn = new SqlParameter();
                    paramValidOn.ParameterName = "@ValidOn";
                    paramValidOn.Value = dealMasterInfo.ValidOn;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramValidOn);

                    SqlParameter paramUserTypes = new SqlParameter();
                    paramUserTypes.ParameterName = "@UserTypes";
                    paramUserTypes.Value = dealMasterInfo.UserTypes;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUserTypes);

                    SqlParameter paramDealCode = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealCode.ParameterName = "@DealCode";
                    paramDealCode.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealCode;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealCode);

                    SqlParameter paramDealPic = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealPic.ParameterName = "@DealPic";
                    paramDealPic.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealPic;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealPic);

                    SqlParameter paramDealStatus = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealStatus.ParameterName = "@DealStatus";
                    paramDealStatus.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealStatus;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealStatus);

                    SqlParameter paramCreatedOn = new SqlParameter();
                    paramCreatedOn.ParameterName = "@CreatedOn";
                    paramCreatedOn.Value = dealMasterInfo.CreatedOn;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCreatedOn);

                    SqlParameter paramModifiedOn = new SqlParameter();
                    paramModifiedOn.ParameterName = "@ModifiedOn";
                    paramModifiedOn.Value = dealMasterInfo.ModifiedOn;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramModifiedOn);

                    SqlParameter paramCreatedBy = new SqlParameter();
                    paramCreatedBy.ParameterName = "@CreatedBy";
                    paramCreatedBy.Value = dealMasterInfo.CreatedBy;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCreatedBy);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
            }

        }

        public void EditDealMaster(DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DealMaster"].ConnectionString;

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spEditDealMaster", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter paramDealAutoID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealAutoID.ParameterName = "@DealAutoID";
                    paramDealAutoID.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealAutoID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealAutoID);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_RestoID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_RestoID.ParameterName = "@FK_RestoID";
                    paramFK_RestoID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_RestoID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_RestoID);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_SnFoodID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_SnFoodID.ParameterName = "@FK_SnFoodID";
                    paramFK_SnFoodID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_SnFoodID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_SnFoodID);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_RoFoodID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_RoFoodID.ParameterName = "@FK_RoFoodID";
                    paramFK_RoFoodID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_RoFoodID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_RoFoodID);

                    SqlParameter paramDealDisPerc = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealDisPerc.ParameterName = "@DealDiscPerc";
                    paramDealDisPerc.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealDisPerc;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealDisPerc);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_RewaID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_RewaID.ParameterName = "@FK_RewaID";
                    paramFK_RewaID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_RewaID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_RewaID);

                    SqlParameter paramstartDate = new SqlParameter();
                    paramstartDate.ParameterName = "@startDate";
                    paramstartDate.Value = dealMasterInfo.startDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramstartDate);

                    SqlParameter paramendDate = new SqlParameter();
                    paramendDate.ParameterName = "@endDate";
                    paramendDate.Value = dealMasterInfo.endDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramendDate);

                    SqlParameter paramValidOn = new SqlParameter();
                    paramValidOn.ParameterName = "@ValidOn";
                    paramValidOn.Value = dealMasterInfo.ValidOn;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramValidOn);

                    SqlParameter paramUserTypes = new SqlParameter();
                    paramUserTypes.ParameterName = "@UserTypes";
                    paramUserTypes.Value = dealMasterInfo.UserTypes;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUserTypes);

                    SqlParameter paramDealCode = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealCode.ParameterName = "@DealCode";
                    paramDealCode.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealCode;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealCode);

                    SqlParameter paramDealPic = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealPic.ParameterName = "@DealPic";
                    paramDealPic.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealPic;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealPic);

                    SqlParameter paramDealStatus = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealStatus.ParameterName = "@DealStatus";
                    paramDealStatus.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealStatus;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealStatus);

                    SqlParameter paramCreatedOn = new SqlParameter();
                    paramCreatedOn.ParameterName = "@CreatedOn";
                    paramCreatedOn.Value = dealMasterInfo.CreatedOn;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCreatedOn);

                    SqlParameter paramModifiedOn = new SqlParameter();
                    paramModifiedOn.ParameterName = "@ModifiedOn";
                    paramModifiedOn.Value = dealMasterInfo.ModifiedOn;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramModifiedOn);

                    SqlParameter paramCreatedBy = new SqlParameter();
                    paramCreatedBy.ParameterName = "@CreatedBy";
                    paramCreatedBy.Value = dealMasterInfo.CreatedBy;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCreatedBy);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Entity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SnackoEntities
{
    public class DealMasterInfo
    {
        public string DealAutoID { get; set; }
        public string FK_RestoID { get; set; }
        public string FK_SnFoodID { get; set; }
        public string FK_RoFoodID { get; set; }
        public string DealDisPerc { get; set; }
        public string FK_RewaID { get; set; }
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
        public string ValidOn { get; set; }
        public string UserTypes { get; set; }
        public string DealCode { get; set; } 
        public string DealPic { get; set; }
        public string DealStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HTML for edit

```
@model SnackoEntities.DealMasterInfo


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DealMasterInfo</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealAutoID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DealAutoID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DealAutoID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealAutoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_RestoID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_RestoID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_RestoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_SnFoodID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_SnFoodID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_SnFoodID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_RoFoodID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_RoFoodID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_RoFoodID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealDisPerc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DealDisPerc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealDisPerc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_RewaID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_RewaID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_RewaID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.startDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.startDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.endDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.endDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.endDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValidOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValidOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserTypes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserTypes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserTypes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DealCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealPic, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DealPic, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealPic, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DealStatus, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModifiedOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModifiedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModifiedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Stored procedure

```
create procedure spEditDealMaster
@DealAutoID varchar(255),
@FK_RestoID varchar(255),
@FK_SnFoodID varchar(255),
@FK_RoFoodID varchar(255),
@DealDiscPerc varchar(255),
@FK_RewaID varchar(255),
@startDate smalldatetime,
@endDate smalldatetime,
@ValidOn varchar(255),
@UserTypes varchar(255),
@DealCode varchar(255),
@DealPic varchar(255),
@DealStatus varchar(255),
@CreatedOn smalldatetime,
@ModifiedOn smalldatetime,
@CreatedBy varchar(255)


as
Begin
    Update DealMaster set DealAutoID=@DealAutoID,FK_RestoID=@FK_RestoID,FK_SnFoodID=@FK_SnFoodID,FK_RoFoodID=@FK_RoFoodID,DealDisPerc =@DealDiscPerc,FK_RewaID=@FK_RewaID,startDate=@startDate,endDate=@endDate,ValidOn=@ValidOn,UserTypes=@UserTypes,DealCode=@DealCode,DealPic=@DealPic,DealStatus=@DealStatus,CreatedOn=@CreatedOn,ModifiedOn=@ModifiedOn,CreatedBy=@CreatedBy
    where DealAutoID=@DealAutoID

End
```

Please help..
Comment if i am missing anything

Comment: Use the SQL profiler to a) see if the query is actually sent and b) what is in it, and then test whether it works when issued directly.

Comment: Sure you didn't left out some code in your question? ;-)

Comment: Check the value of @DealAutoID before calling the stored procedure spEditDealMaster  I suspect it does not exist in the database and that is why nothing is being updated.

Comment: In your edited code, the `Edit_Post(int id)` function appears to accept an ID, load it from the database, then save it back to the database.  What changes did you expect it to apply?

Comment: @KenTucker didnt understand how to do it

Comment: @ZoharPeled The code is complete

Comment: @Goku Zohar's comment is _sarcasm_. The code is a little...shall we say...over-complete. Show only what's actually relevant to the issue, otherwise there is too much for everyone to read. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . And even so, the code is NOT complete because you wrote `UpdateModel(dealMasterInfo);` and we can't see any method called `UpdateModel`

Comment: @Goku "didnt understand how to do it" step through your code with the Visual Studio debugger and watch the value of the relevant variable.

Comment: @Goku put a breakpoint on this line of code                     paramDealAutoID.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealAutoID;  check the value of  dealMasterInfo.DealAutoID exists in the database